# Incorrect addition from a file

Tags: c++

```
  if (infile.is_open())
   {
       int count = 0;
       while (infile)
       {
           string author, ratings;
           getline(infile, author);

           if (author != "")
           {
               getline(infile, ratings);

            // TODO: Create new User object
            User newuser(author, ratings);

            // TODO: Add new User object to vector
            userList.push_back(newuser);

            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << count << " users read in. Closing user file." << endl;
```

The output for this that I am getting is that 86 users were read in from the text file. the correct output is supposed to be 32. I think that it is because I am using a while loop but I am not fully sure.

Comment: what is the infile's datatype  ??  ....IF you took `Filestream infile` the it is some arbitary hex number referencing to memory  (very big number)

Comment: Try opening your file in binary mode.

Comment: @AVIKDUTTA the infile is a list of integers

Comment: @BrandonTuley43 separated by newlines, right?

Comment: @Heron seperated by a space

Comment: the while loop will run as long as the condition is true ..in yoour case as long as infile>0 , so depending on the value of infile the while loop ran which i assume in your case was very large so the loop ran for long time's ...but a normal file could accomodate only (80 or 86 lines ....//not exactly sure about the line numbers) thats why may be you are getting count as 86

Comment: @BrandonTuley43 could you post in the question a small sample of your input? It would help a lot.

Comment: There is a missing } . Where should that one gp?

Comment: Reading in book list from file: books.txt
55 books read in. Closing book list file.
Reading in user list from file: ratings.txt
86 users read in. Closing user file.
Finding recommendations for user: Liz
Most similar user: Moose
We reccomend for you the following books:

Comment: Reading in book list from file: books.txt
   55 books read in. Closing book list file.
   Reading in user list from file: ratings.txt
   86 users read in. Closing user file.
   Finding recommendations for user: Liz
   Most similar user: Moose
   We reccomend for you the following books:

Comment: @BrandonTuley43 I think that's the output...

Comment: @AVIKDUTTA yes i think you are on to what I am asking. It is reading in the number of users but I believe I am getting the incorrect number because I am using a while loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition should be something like

```
while (getline(author, infile) && getline(ratings, infile)) {
    // validate input, then process it
}
```

Then the if (infile.open()) becomes trivial.  There is a '}' missing in the code you posted, which makes it hard to really tell where your counting error is coming from, or maybe that's just the reason, incrementing your count in the wrong place.  Please make sure your examples are complete and possibly even compile.

A little tip, you can just write

```
userList.push_back(User(author, ratings));
```

EDIT:
I created this minimal test code (for you) and tested it on the following file, resulting in the following output. Can you confirm? Please note: The current program doesn't accept newlines in your file, e.g. for grouping various users, however, this is a feature easily added, once the basic program works.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct User {
    string author, ratings;
    User(string auth, string rat) 
        : author(auth), ratings(rat) {}
};

int main()
{
    ifstream ist("test.txt");
    if (!ist) {
        cout << "Could not open file test.txt\n";
        return 1;
    }

    vector<User> userList;
    string author, ratings;
    size_t count = 0;
    while (getline(ist, author) && getline(ist, ratings)) {
        if (author != "" && ratings !=  "") {
            userList.push_back(User(author, ratings));
            ++count;  // in this case, count++ is equivalent
        }
    }
    cout << count << " users read in. Closing user file.\n";
}
```

The file test.txt

```
foo 
bar 
foobar 
lalilu 
myTotalUsersAre 
3
```

Output:

```
3 users read in. Closing user file.
```

Comment: my file does compile and that was my output. Just believe I missed it in the paste sorry!